# Which is the right way to apply PCA on different sized matrices

Tags: pca, matlab, matrix, dimensionality-reduction, sum

I am working on human age classification where I have four descriptors, namely `GEI`, `FED`, `UC` and `UR`. Each descriptor has its own size as follows :

1. GEI(11264, 284)
2. FED(120, 284)
3. UC(89, 284)
4. UR(128, 284)

I want to apply `PCA` to reduce the dimensionality of all matrices (descriptors) in order to make all of them have the same size which have to be the size of the smallest matrix namely `UC`. I am doing this so I can sum all the matrices in order to have only one descriptor (merging).

Do I have to apply `PCA` to all the matrices or it should be only done for the biggest one ?

Comment: I find this question very unclear. Can you please clarify what do these four matrices contain and what do their sized represent? Do all of them have 284 columns? What does 284 signify? Why is the number of rows different?

Comment: @amoeba Those matrices contains data about silhouette's pixel variations. they have the same number of columns 284 (284 persons). The rows number are different beacause each descriptor have it's own number of features.

Comment: Thanks. The idea of applying PCA to four matrices separately and then summing them does not make any sense to me. Yes, you can do PCA on each matrix to reduce them to any $k\times 284$ dimension. But I don't see how summing them after that would be meaningful.

Comment: @amoeba Thank you for this explanation. So summing those four matrices (descriptors) will give me a powerful descriptor that will enhance the classification rate.

Comment: I really doubt that.

Comment: I've tried summing the matrices by reshaping small matrices to the size of the biggest one and then filling empty (new cells) cells with zeros. I got a better classification rate.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to concatenate all 4 matrices into a single one with 11264 + 120 + 89 + 128 measures for each of the 284 individuals. And then perform the PCA on this resulting matrix.

1. in this approach, if you select the PCA to keep *k* dimensions of the combined matrix, you will have the best *k*  uncorrelated, derived (though a linear combinations of the original data) measures for each of your 284 individuals.
2. adding the PCA of each individual matrices makes no sense. Let us assume that the GEI matrix contain genetic information. A PCA that results in  *k* dimensions is the best *k* uncorrelated, derived measures from the raw genetic data.

Let us assume that UR is the answers for a personality test for each of the individuals. A PCA that results in *k* final dimensions is the best *k* uncorrelated, derived measures of personality. The first dimension of the PCA reduced GEI has nothing to do with the first dimension of the PCA reduced UR. and thy cannot be added!!!

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen such case which descriptors are matrices. However, I have a little experience about PCA and I know that it makes normalized linear combinations of descriptors and sort them based on their scores. So your sentence *"I can sum all the matrices in order to have only one descriptor (merging)"*, does not make sense at all.

I strongly recommend you download (free) book "*Introduction to statistical learning*" from [here](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/) and read PCA section. You will obtain a good understanding about the PCA.

Comment: i apreciate you answer. So If applying PCA to reduce the dimensionnality of those matrices to a desired size does not make sense to sum them, do you have any further suggestion that can solve my problem ?

Comment: No, I am sorry.